# bad use of pthread, for waiting response of sockets

Tags: c, sockets, pthreads

my main function is like this :

```
void create_serv_and_init_client(client_t *cl)
{
    static int i = 0;
    pthread_t thread_serv;
    serv_t serv;

    if (i == 0) {
        //cl[0].content = retrieve_info();
        cl[0].connected = 1;
        //PORT = cl[0].content.port;
        serv = create_serv_socket();
        if (pthread_create(&thread_serv, NULL, waiting_connection, \
        (void *)&serv) < 0) {
            perror("could not create thread");
            exit(1);
        }
        cl[0] = create_client(0);
        printf("OK\n");
        i++;

    }
}
```

and the waiting function of the pthread :

```
void *waiting_connection(void *server)
{
    serv_t *serv = (serv_t *)server;

    serv->newSocket = accept(serv->sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv->newAddr, \
    &serv->addr_size);
    if (serv->newSocket < 0) {
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((serv->childpid = fork()) == 0) {
        close(serv->sockfd);
        while (recv(serv->newSocket, serv->buffer, 1024, 0) != 0) {
            printf("Client: %s\n", serv->buffer);
            send(serv->newSocket, serv->buffer, strlen(serv->buffer), 0);
            bzero(serv->buffer, sizeof(serv->buffer));
        }
    }
```

if i comment the `pthread_create` call and call after the `if` the `waiting_connection` function, it will work, so i have a problem with my pthread, but why he doesnt work ? thanks again !

Comment: Gotta ask: if you're already `fork()` ing a child process, why are you also using a pthread? Is there more than one of these listening sockets on different ports ?

Comment: Note that it is rarely, if ever, necessary to splice source lines in C, as the example code does in a couple places.  Doing so is not idiomatic.  Just omit those backslashes and let your statements spread over multiple lines.  Just break lines where whitespace is allowed anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You may have a race condition which may cause undefined behavior.  In create_serv_and_init_client() you define a local variable serv.  The address of this variable is passed to the thread.  When create_serv_and_init_client completes serv will go out of scope, even if the thread is still using it.  As a result the value of serv may no longer be correct.

Comment: "may no longer" ==> "eventually guaranteed not to". `serv` is perpetually dereferenced throughout the read/write loop. If `waiting_connection` doesn't exit *before* `create_serv_and_init_client` returns, there *absolutely* will be a dereference of a dangling pointer.

Comment: So i need to initialize a serv_t variable and call the pthread function in the main before the loop ? @WhozCraig

Comment: @ZahreddineLaidi why isn't your thread proc function actually the one invoking `create_serv_socket` ? It at least appears there is no useful purpose whatsoever for `serv` in the code that creates it, other than to pass it to the thread (which is the part being done incorrectly in the first place). Altternatively, dynamic-allocate the `serv_t` and just pass ownership to the thread func via the thread create user data arg. Let the thread proc manage freeing it when done.

Comment: So where can i call the `waiting_connection` function ? because i have to call it on a pthread, because behind i'm on a loop, and it will freeze the program, so how can i solve this, by calling the function on a pthread ? (if you can show me an example it would be nice, thanks) @WhozCraig

Answer (score 0):

Note a multi-threaded program can really only `fork` to execute a new program using `execve`. For example from Linux manuals:

> - After a `fork()` in a multithreaded program, the child can safely call only async-signal-safe functions (see signal-safety(7)) until such time as it calls `execve(2)`.

`printf` for example can lock the `stdout`. If you happen to fork in while the `printf` lock is held by another thread then crazy things might or might not happen.